# Prove that $\lim \limits_{n\to+\infty}\|\sup_{k>n}u_k-u_n\|=0$

Tags: limits, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $\{u_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in the space $(\mathbb R,d)$ with $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$.
Prove that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\|\sup_{k>n}u_k-u_n\|=0.$$
This seems to be obviously however I can not find an elegant proof.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to rewrite your statement to make it a little clearer. We need to show that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{k > n} |u_k - u_n| = 0.
$$

Let me know if you object to these changes. There are several ways to go about proving this claim, and I am going to choose to do so by contradiction. Many people find proofs by contradiction to be distasteful if a direct proof is available, but I like them because I find it's often natural to proceed by asking "what happens if this statement *isn't* true?". In our case, this would mean that either the limit does not exist, or that it is greater than zero.

So suppose first that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{k > n} |u_k - u_n| = \alpha > 0.
$$

We know that $\{u_k\}$ is Cauchy, and so we can find an integer $j$ so that $|u_m - u_k| < \alpha$ for all $m, k > j$. In particular, $|u_{j+1}, u_k| < \alpha$ for all $k > j+1$. Thus
$$
\sup_{k > j+1}|u_k - u_{j+1}| < \alpha.
$$
Now define $n = j+1$ so we can write this more simply:
$$
\sup_{k > n}|u_k - u_{n}| < \alpha.
$$
Note that this is true for all $n$ large enough, a contradiction (why?). Having seen the contradiction, you can go back and rewrite this more cleanly, even creating a direct proof if you prefer.

There is one consideration left: what if the limit does not exist? You can arrive at a contradiction here by following an analysis similar to the above.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.  Let us prove that the absolute value is eventually at most $\epsilon$; if we can do that for *any* $\epsilon>0$, then the limit must be 0.

Because $(u_n)$ is Cauchy, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\lvert u_n-u_m\rvert<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $n,m\geq N$.

In particular, this means $u_{N+1}\leq\sup_{k>N} u_k\leq u_{N+1}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. So, for $n>N$,
$$
\left\lvert \sup_{k>n} u_k-u_n\right\rvert\leq\Big\lvert\sup_{k>n}u_k-u_{N+1}\Big\rvert+\Big\lvert u_{N+1}-u_n\Big\rvert\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon,
$$
so that the limit must also be at most $\epsilon$. This completes the proof.

Comment: From where comes observation, that $\sup_{k>N}u_k-u_{N+1}\leq\epsilon /2$?

Comment: From the statement following "In particular,".  Subtracting $u_{N+1}$ from each piece of the inequality yields $0\leq\sup_{k>N}u_k-u_{N+1}\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}$; taking absolute values then yields $\lvert \sup_{k>N}u_k-u_{N+1}\rvert\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.